# Should I say "My son's friend's birthday party" or "My son's friend birthday party"?

Tags: possessives

I am trying to say the following:

> I went to a birthday party. That birthday party was for my son's
>   friend.

What possessive form should I use if I want to write it using the **'s** form?

> My **son's friend's** birthday party

or

> My **son's friend** birthday party

I know that this gets overly complicated and I am planning to use the initial, long form, but I am now curious to know what should be the correct way.

Comment: I think the first one is correct, without 's the possession is not specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "longer" form is the only correct one.

Think of it this way: it's **noun**'s birthday party.  But **noun** doesn't have to just be a simple noun (like *my son*), it can also be a *noun phrase* (like *the king of the moon* or *my son's friend*), and **'s** will still go at the end.  You would never say "friend birthday party" if it belongs to *friend*; it's always "friend's birthday party."

Don't be fooled by the fact that **'s** appears twice in "son's friend's birthday party"; the first one indicates that the friend belongs to your son, and the second one indicates that the party belongs to your son's friend.  You can make this as long as you like - *my uncle's barber's priest's next-door neighbor's grandson's roommate's girlfriend's sister's birthday party* if you want - but the **'s** always has to get appended.

Reference: [possession](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine)

Comment: Just for a better understanding: _My son's friend's birthday party_ is correct, while _My son's friend birthday party_ is not. Many thanks for the detailed answer and the useful link :)